# Using COUNT on SQL in GoogleSQL for two variables

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery, count

I am trying to do COUNT for two variables in `rider_type` and three variables in `bike_type`.

I am only able to get it to work like this:

```sql
SELECT bike_type,
COUNT(rider_type) AS num_of_rides
FROM `cyclistic-395223.trips.12_month_tripdata_clean`
WHERE rider_type = 'casual'
GROUP BY bike_type
UNION ALL
SELECT bike_type,
COUNT(rider_type) AS num_of_rides
FROM `cyclistic-395223.trips.12_month_tripdata_clean`
WHERE rider_type = 'member'
GROUP BY bike_type
```

[image: Query Results]

Essentially I want the results to show the COUNT grouped by both bike_type AND rider_type.
Something like this:

[image: Intended Results mocked via Excel]

Database schema:

[image: Dataset Schema]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by more than one field.

```sql
SELECT bike_type, rider_type, COUNT(*) AS num_of_rides
FROM cyclistic-395223.trips.12_month_tripdata_clean
WHERE rider_type IN ('casual', 'member')
GROUP BY bike_type, rider_type
```

Example:

```sql
WITH _table AS (
    SELECT 'casual' AS rider_type, 'docked_bike' AS bike_type UNION ALL
    SELECT 'casual', 'classic_bike'UNION ALL
    SELECT 'casual', 'electric_bike' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'member', 'docked_bike' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'member', 'electric_bike' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'member', 'classic_bike' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'member', 'docked_bike'
  )
SELECT bike_type, rider_type, COUNT(*) AS num_of_rides
FROM _table
WHERE rider_type IN ('casual', 'member')
GROUP BY bike_type, rider_type
```

| bike_type | rider_type | num_of_rides |
| --- | --- | --- |
| docked_bike | casual | 1 |
| classic_bike | casual | 1 |
| electric_bike | casual | 1 |
| docked_bike | member | 2 |
| electric_bike | member | 1 |
| classic_bike | member | 1 |